# Error decoding JSON stream for type [T]: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected END_ARRAY: Attempted to unwrap

Tags: java, rabbitmq, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-rest

Using the Micronaut RabbitMQ with a direct message exchange mechanism, while returning the value from the listener to the producer the JSON parser error appears as described below

```
08:37:58.637 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 8231ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
08:38:05.170 [pool-2-thread-4] ERROR i.m.h.n.stream.HttpStreamsHandler - Error occurred writing stream response: Error decoding JSON stream for type [T]: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected END_ARRAY: Attempted to unwrap 'com.example.domain.ProductViewModel' value from an array (with `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS`) but it contains more than one value
 at [Source: (byte[])"[{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"na"[truncated 125 bytes]; line: 1, column: 80]
io.micronaut.core.serialize.exceptions.SerializationException: Error decoding JSON stream for type [T]: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected END_ARRAY: Attempted to unwrap 'com.example.domain.ProductViewModel' value from an array (with `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS`) but it contains more than one value
 at [Source: (byte[])"[{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"name","price":100.0,"description":"description"},{"id":"111-ffff-111","name":"na"[truncated 125 bytes]; line: 1, column: 80]
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.serdes.JsonRabbitMessageSerDes.deserialize(JsonRabbitMessageSerDes.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQIntroductionAdvice.deserialize(RabbitMQIntroductionAdvice.java:323)
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQIntroductionAdvice.lambda$intercept$22(RabbitMQIntroductionAdvice.java:268)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:132)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTimeoutTimed$TimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FlowableTimeoutTimed.java:101)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.DeferredScalarSubscription.complete(DeferredScalarSubscription.java:132)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onSuccess(SingleToFlowable.java:62)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.onSuccess(RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.onSuccess(RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.onSuccess(SingleDoFinally.java:73)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.onSuccess(RxInstrumentedSingleObserver.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onSuccess(SingleCreate.java:67)
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.reactive.RxJavaReactivePublisher$3.handleDelivery(RxJavaReactivePublisher.java:324)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

**Listener**

```
@RabbitListener
public class ProductListener {
 @Queue(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
    public List<ProductViewModel> find(String text) {
        List<ProductViewModel> value = new ArrayList<>();
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        value.add(new ProductViewModel("111-ffff-111","name",100,"description"));
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Producer**

```
@RabbitClient(ProductTopicConstants.FETE_BIRD_EXCHANGE)
@RabbitProperty(name = "replyTo", value = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")
public interface IProductProducer {
    @Binding(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
    Flowable<ProductViewModel> find(String text);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Get("/{text}")
    public Flowable<ProductViewModel> Find(String text) {
        return iproductProducer.find(text);
    }
```

For the single list of item the exception doesn't appears, however, for more then 1 value the exception appears. Since I am using **Flowable** it should act like a **LIST**

Comment: I think it  tries to serialize array as single value, because your find method didn't returned unique result.  Maybe you need to change return type to Flowable<List<ProductViewModel>>

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan If I change the return type to Flowable<List<ProductViewModel>>, the response contains  2 square brackets as shown below [
    [
        {
            "id": "5fcd9438ee45e2410a5cd989",
            "name": "This is the testing",
            "description": "This is the description",
            "price": 100.0
        }
    ]
]

Comment: @SanJaisy Use `Flowable<List>` with `@Get(single = true)`